# Problem in calling MainWindow class widget function from other class

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

I am developing an UI using QTCreator using CPP. My requirement is to run a UI and need to continuously poll linux Message queue using function msgrcv() whether any data is coming to the queue.Following is some part of my code.

```
namespace Ui 

{

class MainWindow;

}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow

{

Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

private:

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};   

void poll_function()

{

    msgrcv(msgidr, &bufr, sizeof(bufr.mtext), 0, IPC_NOWAIT);
     ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(6);

}

QObject::connect(&poll_timer, &QTimer::timeout,poll_function);

poll_timer.start();
```

In the above code I cannot access ui and stackedwidget inside
poll_function. It is showing an error like " 'ui' was not declared in this scope". Could anyone please give a solution for this problem???

Comment: Can you put your code in code tags for better readability, please?

Comment: Your poll_function needs to be a member function of your MainWindow class in order to access the ui.